# How to key in and display date with hours and minutes into Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, date, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer. I'd like to key in dates with hours and minutes, but the GUI doesn't appear to allow that. While I'm at it, it would be nice to display all date fields as 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' within the Oracle SQL Developer GUI as well.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

After some more poking around I found the right preference setting (screen shot below).

Under "Tools -> Preference" there is a Database:NLS node you can configure. The setting I changed was "Date Format", which I changed to 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'.

I had to restart SQL Developer in order for these changes to take effect. After that, dates display as I want, and the input mask on the GUI also allowed me to edit time.

[image: NLS Setting in Oracle SQL Developer]

Answer (score 0):

Or do this :

alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss';

Works too.